# How to make these two java methods generic

Tags: java, arrays, generics, arraylist

I have these two methods with the same logic, but different parameters. How do I make them into one generic method?

```
boolean exists(int[][] roads, int[] road){
    for(int[] r: roads){
       // code
    }
    return false;
}

boolean exists(ArrayList<int[]> roads, int[] road){
   for(int[] r: roads){
      // code
   }
    return false;
}
```

I want to do something like this

```
<T> boolean exists(Collection<T[]> roads, T[] road){ 
    for(T[] r: roads){
         if(r[0] == road[0])
             return true; 
    }

    return false;
}
```

I get type errors like :

```
required: Collection<T[]>,T[]
  found: int[][],int[]
  reason: cannot infer type-variable(s) T
    (argument mismatch; int[][] cannot be converted to Collection<T[]>)
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in method <T>exists(Collection<T[]>,T[])
```

and i've tried a few other signatures too, but they didn't work either

- `<T,F> boolean exists(F<T[]> roads, T[] road)`
- `<T,F> boolean exists(F<? extends Object> roads, T[] road)`

Comment: FWIW: `X[]` is not a `Collection<X>`, ever.

Comment: Make one method call the other. This way you have only one implementation to maintain, but external code can still call whichever method is more convenient for them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java type parameterization cannot provide any means for you to treat an array as a `Collection` or *vise versa*.  You need a basis for plain polymorphism first, and array types don't have any supertypes in common with non-array types that would be suitable for the polymorphic implementation you want.

My suggestion would be to just drop direct support for the 2D array as an argument.  If a client has a 2D array that they want to pass to your method, let them use `Arrays.asList()` to obtain a `List<int[]>` that they can pass to the Collection-based version of the method (but do read the documentation of `Arrays.asList()` for information on the limitations of this particular `List` implementation).

Comment: +1, though instead of instructing clients to use `Arrays.asList()`, it may make more sense to overload the method with `final boolean exists(int[][] roads, int[] road) { return this.exists(Arrays.asList(roads), road); }`. (Whether this makes sense depends mostly on how common that use-case is expected to be.)

Answer (score 0):

There is no type-safe way to do this. You could create a single Method:

```
boolean exists(Object roads, int[] road)
```

and do instanceOf checks and casts, but you lose more than you gain.